# Is there a Stack Overflow tweet bot?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, twitter, site-specific

Most (all?) of the Stack Exchange sites have dedicated Twitter accounts that tweet questions, pleas for answers, upcoming events, and so forth (e.g. @stackscifi, @stackcooking, @stackparenting, @stacksuper_user, @serverfault).

Does one of these exist for Stack Overflow? @stackoverflow is someone else, and @stackstackoverflow and @stack_stackoverflow don't exist.

@stackexchange follows all (?) of the individual accounts, and doesn't appear to follow one for Stack Overflow. I've tried searching Twitter, but there's so much Stack Exchange content on Twitter that even if the account did exist, I'm not sure it would be visible in the noise.

Comment: note that new twitter account names are now limited to 15 characters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No -- we can't obtain `@stackoverflow` (although we've tried), and I'm not entirely sure Stack Overflow really needs promotion on Twitter in the way the other sites do...

Comment: IMO the accounts aren't just about promoting the site as a whole, but also promoting specific questions, answers, events, blog posts, and so on.  They also make it even easier to share great questions / answers.  Stack Overflow is so noisy/busy now that curated feeds are even more important than they are for the smaller sites.  (Assuming that the tweets are a sort of "best of SO").

Comment: "best of SO" is kind of .. a paradox, since we don't actually *want* hyper-popular questions as they tend to degrade into "favorite programming cartoon" and the like. It's tricky to walk the line

Comment: [@stackoveflow](https://twitter.com/stackoverflow) belongs to the company but it's not used as bot to post questions.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow does not have a Twitter bot.

[The list of sites on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites) includes Twitter links to the bots for each site. We can see that Stack Overflow is one of the few site without one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an unofficial one [here](http://twitter.com/stackalert) which I created then bequeathed to [Teifion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15/teifion). If I recall correctly, it was skewed towards specific tags.

He's not particularly regular around here anymore, so I don't know if he's actively maintaining it or not.

Comment: yes, Teifion did bequeath those twitter accounts on us, for which we were very grateful, and swag was had!

Comment: @Jeff, ha! I missed out on that one then. I even reserved the domain at the same time, but let it drop after a year...

Comment: No twitter posts since 2009... ?