# What is the preferred way to mention Stack Overflow from Twitter?

Tags: discussion, twitter, social-networking, sharing

I wanted to tweet something on the lines of "Stack Overflow is awesome". When I do this kind of stuff, I usually use a username (for example: [@microsoft](https://twitter.com/#!/microsoft)) or a hashtag ([#linux](https://twitter.com/#!/search?q=#Linux))

I found [@stackoverflow](https://twitter.com/#!/stackoverflow), but it seems it is from someone unrelated with Stack Overflow.

Is there a Twitter account I can reference, or should I use a hash-tag? Should I just point to the site?

Thanks!

(Notice: I've seen lots of questions regarding Twitter and Stack Overflow, but those are mostly about integration/login with Twitter for the users accounts; I'm just asking for a single account for Stack Overflow; probably for announcements and PR, which is different)

Comment: I use the hash tag `#StackOverflow` - no idea whether it's "official" or not.

Comment: I also failed to find an offical Stack Overflow twitter! We have @STackExchange but that's all I found, all other sites have one.

Comment: Related: [Is there a Stack Overflow tweet bot?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106022/is-there-a-stack-overflow-tweet-bot)

Comment: shouldn't SO claim that name for themselves? see https://support.twitter.com/articles/15362-inactive-account-policy

Comment: I think there is a subtle self-reference your question @BoltClock's a Unicorn, was the question who is @stackoverflow?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The list of people who use the [#StackOverflow](https://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23StackOverflow) hash tag includes:

- [Jeff Atwood](https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror)
- [Joel Spolsky](https://twitter.com/#!/spolsky)
- [StackExchange](https://twitter.com/#!/StackExchange)
- [Jon Skeet](https://twitter.com/#!/jonskeet)
- [Bill the Lizard](https://twitter.com/#!/lizardbill)
- [BoltClock](https://twitter.com/#!/BoltClock)
- [Tim Post](https://twitter.com/#!/tinkertim)
- and so on...

SE founders, employees, mods, top contributors, etc.  That's official enough for me :)

Comment: A few these will sometimes use #stackexchange instead, but you can add me to the #stackoverflow list ;)

Comment: [Obligatory](https://twitter.com/BoltClock/status/159351773683916800)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: You're a mod _and_ a unicorn.  It doesn't get more official than that.  (You were also near the top of the recent hash tag uses, among the names which I actually recognized.)

Comment: I'm _not_ converting this to CW because I fear SPAM that would dilute the intent of your answer.

Comment: Alright! The hash tag it is, then! Cheers!