# What is the Twitter hashtag for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, twitter

I tweet useful Stack Overflow questions so I can find them again easily. Is there a common hashtag for Stack Overflow like #stackoverflow or #so?

Comment: You could also mark a question as favorite if you want to find it later.

Comment: Well.. if you are tweeting them so that you can find them again it doesn't really matter - use what ever you can remember easily. `#stackoverflow` sounds about right though... That being said, I've voted to close this post as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: #stackoverflow seems to be used fairly often, and it's what I follow. It does however get you a surprising amount off pictures from people showing of stacks of money as well. And I'm pretty sure they are not developers.

Comment: This sounds like a fiddly and inefficient method to find questions later. Bookmarks in a "Useful Stack Questions" folder would surely be better?

Comment: Twitter is anarchy. Pick your own hashtag and stick to it.

Comment: Since it's his own Twitter, he can find those questions back by going to his own Twitter page. I think the OP wants to know if the Stack Overflow community has a (semi-)official hashtag.

Comment: Searching for [#StackOverflow](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23StackOverflow&src=typd) turns up a lot more relevant results than [#SO](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23SO&src=typd).

Comment: Bit puzzled about the downvotes and the close votes. Here's a heavily upvoted duplicate, with a not-so-much-opinion-based answer: [What is the preferred way to mention Stack Overflow from Twitter?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119338/162704) (spoiler: All the cool kids use #StackOverflow)

Comment: #TonyThePony­­­

Comment: Again with the downvotes. Why is asking a valid question getting downvoted? This has more to do with branding and searching. If everyone in the Stack Overflow community (who tweets) uses #so, then I want to use #so. Other sites (and tv shows) publicize their hashtags, so there is a common hashtag everyone uses.

Comment: Enclined to agree, voting to reopen (but to give fair warning once its open I'm going to vote to close as a duplicate of that link)

Comment: I posted this on Stack Overflow, after a search there did not turn up an answer (all posts were about doing things to hashtags programmatically). Was suggested to move to meta, which I did. Forgot to do a search on meta before moving the question.

Comment: Mild duplication isn't a bad thing

Comment: If you see a hashtag of #SO then you'd probably think *"I wonder what SO stands for?"* However, if you see a tweet mentioning #StackOverflow you'll think *"That's about Stack Overflow"*. It removes the need to actually expend any thought about what you're reading.

Comment: But as most tweeters know; the shorter the hashtag, the better. I don't know where they came up with 140 characters as the limit, but every character matters.

Comment: @CigarDoug I have always seen that as a reason to not use twitter, sadly I am in a minority